Dynamically Find if Object Support Batch
I'm building a dynamic batch to get all objects and to loop through them (pet project/inquiring minds thing more than anything), but for some objects I hit the error below:

FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: The requested operation is not
supported by this SObject

Do all objects support batching? Is there a way to tell via describe, or other method, if they do not?
Demo code, using one of the non supported objects:
public class exampleBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    String query = 'SELECT id,createdbyid,createddate FROM ActivityFieldHistory';
    
    public exampleBatch(){}
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);//error here = The requested operation is not supported by this SObject
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){}
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}


Have you tried dumping the detail of a DescribeSObjectResult to see if this has isQueryable set false? Also, be aware that some objects cannot be queried without explicitly specifying a context, such as a durable ID or some specific relationship.

Hmm I have filtered out the non queryable objects, but presumably ActivityFieldHistory is a big object behind the scenes hence why that particular object fails on getQueryLocator

Probably one of those that wants a "context". What do you see if you try that query directly in the developer console? I got UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1048660839-1065326 (-1470627161). Not helpful, but possibly related to needing context, just not telling you!

Via exec anon in dev console : Select Count() = GACK, SELECT Id FROM ActivityFieldHistory = returned records.  Query Editor returns rows as well.

All history objects are BigObjects. Querying on other history objects are supported via Batch.
But ActivityFieldHistory is a very unique object.
All other history objects are store in Oracle, but ActivityFieldHistory gets store in Apache Hbase, hence none of the fields on ActivityFieldHistory object is indexed.
Hence this object cannot be queried via Batch class.
If you are using salesforce inspector extension, then you would be able to see the value of the query.

If you try this tooling API query, you will see none of the fields are indexed here, hence this object cannot be queried in a batch class.
SELECT Id, EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName, IsIndexed, QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'ActivityFieldHistory'


Appreciate the answer but that was just one example object (happened to be the first alphabetically). The question is, is there a way to tell dynamically if an object supports batch

You can try tooling API to check if Id field is indexed at least.
SELECT QualifiedApiName, IsIndexed FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'ActivityFieldHistory' LIMIT 200 If not then the object wont work in Batch. Do you have any examples to prove this assumptions is correct or not?

AIModel and ActivityRecurrence2 have isIndexed = True but get the error on getQueryLocator

How about a combination of
"Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('AIModel') != null" && "Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('AIModel').getDescribe().isQueryable()" And tooling API to check Id is indexed ?
